# matMenuTriggerFor and double click not working together

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

Hello all I am stuck in one place , i have angular application in which I am using Angular material mat-menu, now here my mat-menu is working fine but I want one more mouse double click which is not working properly with `matMenuTriggerFor` sometimes it gets called sometimes not, Please help how to make double click event and `matMenuTriggerFor` work together.

```
<button mat-icon-button #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger"  [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (dblclick)="doubleClick($event)">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
 </button>
```

So here menu is opening properly, but double click function sometimes get called and sometimes not if I remove matMenuTriggerFor than double click work perfectly. Sorry for my grammar mistake.